# How do i find the culprit of "exceeded mem limit" errors on iOS devices visiting a particular web page?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, webkit, safari-web-inspector

With a physical iPhone attached to the dev tools on my laptop, the memory usage of [this web page](https://nypost.com/2023/10/11/australian-swimmers-almost-walk-into-shark-as-it-swims-close-to-shore/) consistently grows until it reaches the memory limit of the device (in my case, about 1.5GB)

The safari dev tools has a memory profiler timeline which breaks down memory usage into categories including "Javascript", "Layers", and "Page"; is there a way to break these down further to individual scripts/resources?

I have also tried looking at the Javascript allocations profiler, but the computed heap size reported in its snapshots never comes anywhere close to the 700+ MB of "JavaScript" memory usage reported by the Memory profiler.